# An exercise about $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $1\leq p<\infty$ and $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^p(\mathbb{R})$, show that for any set $M$ with finite measure in $\mathbb{R}$, $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_M|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\mathrm{d}x=0.$$

I have no idea about how to solve it... Need some hints about this question.

Comment: Do you have some idea if we just assume $f\in L^p([-K,K])$ and we extend it by $0$ to give meaning to $f(x+h)$?

Comment: The first question is: Why does this integral exist at all? I don't see it at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. The integral might not exist for any $h$. Example: Set $I_n := [n,n+\frac 1{n^2}]$ and
$$
M = \bigcup_{n=2}^\infty I_n
\quad\text{as well as}\quad
f = \sum_{n=2}^\infty n\cdot\chi_{I_n}.
$$
Then $|M| < \infty$ and $f\in L^1_{\rm loc}(\mathbb R)$.

Let $h\in\mathbb R$. Then there exists $N$ such that $\frac 1{N^2}<|h|$. Hence, if $n\ge N$ and $x\in I_n$, then $x+h\notin I_n$. So,
\begin{align}
\int_M|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx
&= \sum_{n=2}^\infty\int_{I_n}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx\,\ge\,\sum_{n=N}^\infty\int_{I_n}|f(x+h)-f(x)|\,dx\\
&= \sum_{n=N}^\infty\int_{I_n}f(x)\,dx = \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac 1n = \infty.
\end{align}

---

The claim is true for bounded $M$, though. To see this, we prove the following: If $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$, then
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\,dx = 0.
$$
The claim for bounded $M$ then follows from there. Define the translation operator $T_h : L^p(\mathbb R)\to L^p(\mathbb R)$ by $h\in\mathbb R$ as $T_hf(x) := f(x+h)$. It is easily seen that $T_h$ is linear and an isometry, i.e., $\|T_hf\|_p = \|f\|_p$ for $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$.

We have to show that $\|T_hf-f\|_p\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ for each $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$. For $f\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ (continuous functions with compact support) this is evident. But $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb R)$. So, if $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\phi\in C_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $\|f-\phi\|_p < \epsilon$. Hence,
$$
\|T_hf-f\|_p\,\le\,\|T_h(f-\phi)\|_p + \|T_h\phi-\phi\|_p + \|\phi-f\|_p\,\le\,2\epsilon + \|T_h\phi-\phi\|_p.
$$
Letting $h\to 0$ we see that
$$
0\,\le\,\limsup_{h\to 0}\|T_hf-f\|_p\,\le\, 2\epsilon.
$$
But $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, so $\lim_{h\to 0}\|T_hf-f\|_p = 0$.

Comment: You're right. I'll correct that.